# $.isNumeric not doing anything

Tags: jquery

It seems that `isNumeric` won't work with this type of code, I might be writing something wrongly. Could anyone assist me and explain me what am I doing wrong?

```
$("form.offer_post").submit(function(e) {
    var name = $('#project_info').val().trim(),
        price = $.trim($('#offer_price').val().trim());

    if (price.length<1) { 
        if(!$.isNumeric($('#offer_price').val())) {
            alert("Offer MUST be numeric!"); 
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        alert("Please enter the project price"); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (name.length<1) { 
        alert("Please enter some description for your offer"); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }


});
```

Everything besides numeric check works perfectly.

Comment: You're only testing `$.isNumeric` when the length of the `price` is `0` - so it will never pass

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan I overlooked that one!

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Using isnan jquery to find the not numeric values.

Example :- isNaN('TEXT') //true

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed as you only test for `$.isNumeric` when the length of the `price` value is `0`. Therefore the condition will never pass. Instead, separate both of those conditions, like this:

```
$("form.offer_post").submit(function(e) {
    var name = $('#project_info').val().trim(),
        price = $('#offer_price').val().trim();

    if (price.length < 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please enter the project price');
    } 
    if (!$.isNumeric(price)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Offer MUST be numeric!');
    } 
    if (name.length < 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please enter some description for your offer');
    }
});
```